# How to survive the transition from tabbed-based to buffer-based coding (Vim)

Tags: vim, tabs, buffer

I recently changed from notepad++ to Vim. In notepad++ I used to be aware of my open files by
seeing them as tabs, so when I wanted to close or change them I just pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>. In Vim there are also tabs, but when I use them I feel like I'm just going back to my notepad++ way of managing my files. Is there a good way of list, manage, switch and delete buffers other than splitting them?

Comment: This helps a bit: " set buffers commands
nnoremap <silent> <M-F8> :BufExplorer<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :bn<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <S-F8> :bp<CR>

Comment: I just wanted to offer my support. I'm working in a team where everyone uses Notepad++, and I'm the only Vimmer, and they never listen to me. They are blind to the light. The horror.

Comment: I use tabs in Vim all the time. If you have multiple buffers open, you can open tabs for all of them using `:tab ball`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep.  I recommend a buffer explorer plugin as well as learning buffer commands. I use this plugin.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42

The buffer paradigm is quite elegant once you are used to it. Less visual clutter. but you are free with vim to find your own thing

Answer (score 3):

You can use these commands:

- `ls` - list all open buffers
- `bp`, `bn` - switch to the previous or next buffer
- `b` *number* - switch to the buffer with that number
- `b` *text* - switch to the buffer whose name includes the string *text*

Answer (score 3):

I've tried several setups for Vim. My previous was one where I tried to use tabs instead of buffers. It was not very satisfying.

Now I've returned to buffers and for navigating files and buffers I use only the [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) and [fuzzyfinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) (I guess ex Textmate users may prefer fuzzyfinder_textmate) plugins, both are great.

For locating files I use either NERDTree bound to  n or fuzzyfinder's File mode. For navigating open buffers I use fuzzfinder's buffer mode solely, bound to  b.

Recently I also discovered that I could switch to the previously open buffer with Ctrl-6 (I think maybe that is Ctrl-^ on most keyboard).

Comment: Hm, i just noticed that <leader> in front of n and b got stripped…

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to deal with buffers in vim.

CTRL-^ to switch between buffers.

:q is the same as Ctrl-W

For further details see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching

Answer (score 0):

BufferExplorerLight

```
" quick buffer selection including unlisted
nnoremap <leader>b :buffers!<cr>:buffer<space>
```

Alternatively

```
nnoremap <leader>b :buffer<space> <c-d>
```

But really you have to try [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984)!